# Python - Finding substrings related to specific keywords

Tags: python

I would like to ask you how I can extract substrings related to some keywords.

For example I have the following text:

```
mystring = "Commission 0,0000 Packaging 0,0426 Discount 0,0120 Transport 0,0690 F YEB 0,0000 Commission 0,0000 Payment discount 0,0000 % Other discount 0,0000 YEB 4,0700 % Industrial 0,3856"
```

I would like to extract the numeric value after some keywords, for example: "Discount" and "Other discount". I was trying with the following code:

```
    test = re.compile(r"""(
    (Discount\s\d*)
    (Other\sdiscount\s\d*)
    )""", re.VERBOSE)

pr = test.findall(mystring)
```

I would like to obtain (in this case) a pair --> Discount : 0,0120  and Other discount : 0,0000
But it could be also enough obtain a list like the following one:

```
["Discount 0,0120", "Other discount 0,0000"]
```

I really thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: the following regex should work `(Discount \d+\,\d+).*(Other discount \d+\,\d+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had better luck with re.search. Also you were missing \d,\d to capture numbers before and after the comma.

```
import re

mystring = "Commission 0,0000 Packaging 0,0426 Discount 0,0120 Transport 0,0690 F YEB 0,0000 Commission 0,0000 Payment discount 0,0000 % Other discount 0,0000 YEB 4,0700 % Industrial 0,3856"

pattern = "(Discount\s\d+,\d+)(.*)(Other\sdiscount\s\d+,\d+)"

p = re.search(pattern, mystring)

p.groups()
>> ('Discount 0,0120',
 ' Transport 0,0690 F YEB 0,0000 Commission 0,0000 Payment discount 0,0000 % ',
 'Other discount 0,0000')
```

Comment: Thank you Correy, so if I well understood: 
1) If I create a pattern composed by groups (3 in this case), the text that does not match with the first (or last) of them, will not be take by the procedure. That's why the first piece of string it didn't appeared in the p.groups()
2) You added a (.*) in the middle of my previous group in order to take everything between them
3) There is no way to obtain just the two substring without the middle one? ' Transport 0,0690 .....' ?
Many thanks in advance
Andrea

Comment: I would say your understanding is correct. You can remove the center grouping to only receive a tuple of two entries.
pattern = "(Discount\s\d+,\d+).*(Other\sdiscount\s\d+,\d+)"
My go to regex scratchpad is regex101.com. It does a live test, and shows you a lot of helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop could be done as well:

```
mystring = "Commission 0,0000 Packaging 0,0426 Discount 0,0120 Transport 0,0690 F YEB 0,0000 Commission 0,0000 Payment discount 0,0000 % Other discount 0,0000 YEB 4,0700 % Industrial 0,3856"
list_mystring = mystring.split()
discount_value = "" # initalize var
other_discount = "" # initalize var
for i in range(len(list_mystring)):
    if list_mystring[i] == "Discount":
        discount_value = list_mystring[i+1]
    if (list_mystring[i] == "Other") and (list_mystring[i+1]=="discount"):
        other_discount = list_mystring[i+2]
my_pair = (discount_value, other_discount)
print(my_pair)
```

Output here is: ('0,0120', '0,0000').

Comment: Many thanks Gloria, I really appreciated your help.
But in a general way I would like to avoid to use the split method due to the fact that some substrings will have some white space in the middle that I needed.
So this is the reason why I tried with regex, in order to be able to manipulate the text strings in several ways (I don't know if it is the right method yet).

Answer (score 0):

Truly, this is not the most efficient method, but still it works:

```
mystring = "Commission 0,0000 Packaging 0,0426 Discount 0,0120 Transport 0,0690 F YEB 0,0000 Commission 0,0000 " \
           "Payment discount 0,0000 % Other discount 0,0000 YEB 4,0700 % Industrial 0,3856"

items_list = []
i = 0
for j, char in enumerate(mystring[:-2]):
    if char.isdigit() and mystring[j + 2].isalpha() or mystring[j + 2] == '%':
        if mystring[j + 2] == '%':
            items_list.append(mystring[i:j+1])
            i = j + 4
        else:
            items_list.append(mystring[i:j + 1])
            i = j + 2
items_list.append(mystring[i:])

def itemDigit_sep(item):
    item = item.replace(',', '.')
    for i, char in enumerate(item[:-2]):
        if char.isalpha() and item[i + 2].isdigit():
            return (item[:i + 1], float(item[i +2:]))

item_value_list = [itemDigit_sep(item) for item in items_list]

[('Commission', 0.0), ('Packaging', 0.0426), ('Discount', 0.012), ('Transport', 0.069), ('F YEB', 0.0), ('Commission', 0.0), ('Payment discount', 0.0), ('Other discount', 0.0), ('YEB', 4.07), ('Industrial', 0.3856)]
```

or you can even map all the transactions to its corresponding value.

```
item2value_dict = {}
for item_value in items_list:
    item, value = item2Value_sep(item_value)
    item2value_dict[item] = value

{'Commission': 0.0, 'Packaging': 0.0426, 'Discount': 0.012, 'Transport': 0.069, 'F YEB': 0.0, 'Payment discount': 0.0, 'Other discount': 0.0, 'YEB': 4.07, 'Industrial': 0.3856}
```